# UI-Grid setting template for filter options

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a table created with UI-Grid, with multi-select filters above.  Everything works fine.

However, I used a `cellTemplate` for the one column, as I need the values (money) formatted correctly.  I have a function that I pipe the value into, which returns it formatted nicely:

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">{{COL_FIELD | moneyFormatter }}</div>'
```

The values in the filter populate automatically, however it uses the raw values, not the nicely-formatted ones.  I need to get the formatted values in there.

I know of `selectOptions`, which you set in the columnDefs.  But as far as I'm aware, it takes a list of predetermined raw values and translations.

Is there a way to pass sort of a function to `selectOptions`?  Is there a way to set a template for the`<option>`s, similar to `cellTemplate`?  Or is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make use of `headerCellFilter`

From the docs:

> headerCellFilter is a filter to apply to the content of the column
>   header

For the column which you want the dropdown formatted,  you can do this in `columnDefs`-

```
{field:'id', displayName:'ID', headerCellFilter:'moneyFormatter'}
```